# Стоит ли закрывать сканер в конце выполнения кода?

Tags: java

У меня программы 2 файла.

1)

```
package com;

public class first {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        second bmw = new second();
        System.out.println("Машина BMW:");
        bmw.input();
        System.out.println("Скорость: " + bmw.speed + ". Вес: " + bmw.weight + ". Цвет: " + bmw.color + ". Тип: " + bmw.type);
        System.out.println("Машина Merc:");
        second merc = new second();
        merc.input();
        System.out.println("Скорость: " + merc.speed + ". Вес: " + merc.weight + ". Цвет: " + merc.color + ". Тип: " + merc.type);
    }
}
```

2. 

```
package com;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class second {
    int speed, weight;
    String color, type;
    
    public void input() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ВВЕДИТЕ ДАННЫЕ ОБЪЕКТА!");
        System.out.println("Скорость: ");
        speed = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Вес: ");
        weight = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Тип: ");
        input.nextLine();
        type = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Цвет: ");
        color = input.nextLine();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Я хочу создать 2 объекта, а данные для него вводить 1 сканером. Когда начинаю вводить данные второго объекта, то появляется ошибка. Если же не закрывать сканер, то ошибки нет. Как тут быть?

Comment: так откройте сканер в головном коде и передайте его в метод input параметром

Comment: Сделал, спасибо!

Comment: если вы поток не открывали, то и закрывать его не надо. system.in открывали не вы. если вы его закроете, то открыть больше не сможете, потому что изначально он открыт не вами и средств открыть его не существует в принципе. посему закрывать system.in либо сканнер, обращающийся к system.in, не нужно

Comment: Сканнер закрывать надо осторожно. Он читает из потока сколько-то символов вперёд, никто не знает сколько. Если вы один раз надели сканнер на поток, вы уже не сможете пользоваться потоком как раньше. Закроете сканнер, прочитанные вперёд символы пропадут. Закрывать сканнер можно только если вы решили закрыть поток с которым сканнер работает. Никто никогда этого не делает, сборщик мусора всё сам уберет. Один поток - один сканнер и никаких закрытий.